# Checkstyle Jenkins - How do I Configure Checkstyle in Jenkins?

Tags: plugins, jenkins, checkstyle

I am new to using Jenkins and I recently built a project with it and installed the "Checkstyle" plugin and received a report.

I want to know how I can configure "Checkstyle" to, let's say, ignore whitespaces or other criteria that may come up?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins simply reads the checkstyle report after it was run in the course of a build, and is extraneous to the question.  To configure checkstyle, you want to modify or create checkstyle.xml (the location is configurable via method based your choice of build automation tool, such as [maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html).  The [checkstyle manual](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html) has further details on how to accomplish any checks you may desire.

Comment: I checked my system for a "checkstyle.xml" and all that shows up is a "checkstyle-config.xml" file, which is associated with my Eclipse plugin. The project I am building is not based off my local machine, but a URL pulled from Git. 

Not sure what my next steps would be...

Comment: The checkstyle.xml does not necessarily exist yet, which would cause checkstyle to roll with defaults  Your next step would be to add that xml to your project where your build tool expects to see it (or where you may have configured it to look).  Once that's done, Jenkins would be able to read the report file that would get generated in your build directory.

Is this git public?  Can you post it?  Also, what build tool are you using?  I linked manual entries for two of the more popular ones in my answer.

Comment: This is through my employer. I was assigned to research how to limit what Checkstyle can check. The steps would be: Open Jenkins Job, Build Project, after build is done, email Checkstyle report to people. Also, we are using Maven.

I'm just confused as to where I place this checkstyle.cml so that when Jenkins runs and we build the project, it references the xml to determine what TO and NOT TO check.

Comment: You can actually put it wherever you want then, and feed its location to your pom, as per: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#configLocation.  The location is resolved as a resource, URL, then file, so as long as you point it to a checkstyle xml, so just point it to wherever you put your file.  Since this is for your company, you may want to host it on an internal server and just have everyone reference its url.

Remember that Jenkins only role in this is to read a report file after the build is done (the report is output in your build folder).

Comment: First, I'd like to say thank you so much for the help, it means a lot!
Also, when I open my Jenkins job and hit "Build", it obviously starts to build the code and then at the end/during the build, a visual graph is displayed at the dashboard telling me what was wrong and I can further investigate this by expanding the graph. So is this the result of reading a report file after the build is done? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "...you may want to host it on an internal server and just have everyone reference its url." What do you mean by this? Where can I reference the XML with my configurations in Jenkins?

Comment: Since the configuration can resolve to a url, just about anything that can accept an http connection.  For example: "http://server.my-company.com/directory/folder/important/checkstyle.xml" would be suitable.  Alternatively, just stash the file on your jenkins box and reference the local file path directly ("C:\path\to\checkstyle.xml" or "/var/whatever/checkstyle.xml".

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense for sure. Hmm, but I think I want to know where in Jenkins do I put the URL? Like which specific text box within the Jenkins job. I was looking through my job and it looks like there are various places.

Comment: You would not touch the Jenkins job, the Jenkins checkstyle plugin has no part in the invocation or configuration of checkstyle.  The only thing it does is reads a checkstyle-report.xml in your workspace generated by way of a checkstyle invocation (such as running maven with a checkstyle:checkstyle goal).  Pointing to your checkstyle.xml location is done via your project's pom, as per http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#configLocation.  This also has the added benefit of allowing everyone to run checkstyle locally, should they desire.

Comment: Is there anyway you can send me visuals? That would be amazing!
matthewytark@gmail.com